# CSS3 black bar on side of navbar (I think it has to do with the way I've set up transitions.)

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a navbar with a opacity transition. The way I've set it up is I have the .rounded class with black background color, and on top of that I target the li's in the ul, adding the image graphic and transitions. Then finally I have a li:hover, changing the opacity (showing through to the .rounded.)

My problem is that for some reason, the main .rounded class has a black bar sticking out as shown: [image: http://i.imgur.com/zUYiHss.png]

Here is my full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/YVTBt/

The navbar part of the HTML:

```
<ul class="rounded"> <!-- Navbar-->
      <li class="sideBarButton">
        <a href="../www.google.com">
         Home
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sideBarButton">
        <a href="../www.google.com">
         About
        </a>
      </li>
           <li class="sideBarButton">
        <a href="../www.google.com">
            Download
        </a>
      </li>
        <li class="sideBarButton">
        <a href="../www.google.com">
         Screenshots
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sideBarButton">
        <a href="../www.google.com">
         Licence
        </a>
      </li>
           <li class="sideBarButton">
        <a href="../www.google.com">
            Others' Stuff
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sideBarButton">
        <a href="../google.com">
            Support This
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="sideBarButton">
        <a href="../google.com">
            About Me
        </a>
      </li>
        <li class="sideBarButton">
        <a href="../google.com">
            Help
         </a>
      </li>
    </ul> <!--- Navbar-->
```

The relevant part of the CSS:

```
.rounded > li:first-child
{
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    background-image: url(woodbutton.gif);
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}
.rounded > li:last-child
{
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    background-image: url(woodbutton.gif);
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}
.rounded>li:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    background-image: url(woodbutton.gif);
    transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I strongly recommend looking at the fiddle, though. I've been struggling with this for a few days now, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, user-agent sylesheets adds some left padding to `ul` element by default.

In this particular case you can just reset it by setting

```
.rounded {
  padding: 0
}
```

See [**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YVTBt/1/)

Comment: Thank you! Didn't notice that. Now I have a slightly different problem, the navbar is no longer centered. Is there another quick property for that? Edit: Other answer worked for me. :D Edit again: Other answer doesn't keep the fade-in transition working.

Comment: Ok, after changing the margins to work, I centered it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try with removing the `position:absolute` tag on the `.rounded` class.

See http://jsfiddle.net/damoiser/5Nurg/

Then, you can put some `background-color` on the `li`s elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't keep the fade in transition. Any ideas for how to get that back in again? Even after adding background color to .rounded>li.

Comment: @user2779909 mmm seen, seems that doesn't take the background:black anymore even forcing in the child elements. I think that the backround-image of the li elements can cause some "conflicts" with the background. Another solution, maybe not so elegant, is to place a div behind the menu with the background black.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks anyway! The only problem I foresee is that I'm floating the navbar.